# preg_replace, how to set string

Tags: php

```
$item->description = preg_replace("/\<center\>\<a href=\"(.*)\"\>\<img alt=\"\" src=\"(.*)\" \/\>\<\/a\>\<\/center\>/", "$2", $item->description);
```

But I need to put result `$2` into string `$item->image`.
How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
$item->image = preg_replace("/.*\<center\>\<a href=\"(.*)\"\>\<img alt=\"\" src=\"(.*)\" \/\>\<\/a\>\<\/center\>.*/", "$2", str_replace("\n", '', $item->description));
```

How ever do not use regex for parsing html use instead [`DOM`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) instead

Comment: No, Then $item->image will be with all content, which have $item->description.

Comment: No, I need to parse XML and $item->description have html code and I want to clear it. Btw, this script will work on time per hour.

Comment: So your `$item->image` how should be? *You* said that `$2` should be assigned to `$item->image`.

Comment: Yes, I need only `$2`, but not all $item->description.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Try now. I've added `.*` at the beginning and at the end of regex.

Comment: Now, it's better, but it remove only peace of code in the end.